# creating excel macro for adding rows

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

and i want to create a macro in excel that add a row when i reach a certain cell.
any help appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You can add the below to the SelectionChange event of the worksheet and change the condition as necessary.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If ActiveCell.Row = 2 Then
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert
End If

End Sub
```